# Swift - Change presenting view controller background color when modal is dismissed

Tags: ios, swift

I am presenting a modal that slides from the bottom when a button is clicked. When that happens, I change the presenting VC alpha so that it is slightly greyed out.
Now I'm trying to dismiss this effect when the modal is dismissed, but I've had no luck so far:

PRESENTING VC:

```
func onIconTapped() {
    self.view.alpha = 0.8
    let vc = MyViewController)
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

PRESENTED VC:

```
override func loadView() {
    view = MyDetailsView()
    self.view = view

    (view as! MyDetailsView).closeButtonTapped = { [weak self] in
         self?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
         self?.presentingViewController?.view.alpha = 1
    } 
}
```

Any ideas how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Your code looks fine. Please clarify what do you mean "I've had no luck so far".

Comment: I mean that the code pasted above doesn't achieve the expected result. Changing the view.alpha to 1 when the modal is dismissed has not effect and alpha remains at 0.8

Comment: Is presentingViewController not nil in the row with setting alpha?

Comment: try to put whole code so we can understand.

Comment: @MikhailVasilev I checked and it's not nil

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the Adaptive Presentation Delegate like this:

```swift
class FirstController: UIViewController, UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate {



    // MARK: - Helpers
    func route() {
        let controller = SecondController()
        controller.presentationController?.delegate = self
        self.view.alpha = 0.8

        present(controller, animated: true)
    }


    // MARK: - Presentation Delegate
    func presentationControllerDidDismiss(_ presentationController: UIPresentationController) {
        self.view.alpha = 1.0
    }
}
```